# I am trying to replace a frames based web solution with iFrames and I've got one set up as the menu and the other set up as the content

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, navigation, frames

I am trying to replace a frames based web solution with  iFrames and I've got one set up as the menu and the other set up as the content.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Frames Test</title>
<style>
.menu {
float:left;
width:20%;
  height:80%;
}
.mainContent {
  float:left;
  width:75%;
  height:80%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<iframe class="menu" src="menu.html"></iframe>
<iframe class="mainContent" src="events.html"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

My question is, how do I get links in the menu frame to populate the content frame?